# Cross between an Enum and a Dictionary

Tags: java, data-structures

In my Java project, I have a need to work with a handful of strings (about 10-30 at a time). I want a data structure to hold them, with properties like so:

1. Can assign a unique name to each string
2. The unique names can be used in the code just as if they were variables, with support for IDE auto-complete, no calling getValue() or toString(), etc.
3. Can iterate over each value in the data structure

In practice, I'd want the code to look something like this:

```
MagicalDataStructure<String> mds = new MagicalDataStructure(
       FirstString = "foo",
       SecondString = "bar",
);

/*
This section would output:
   foo
   bar
*/
for (String value : mds) {
    System.out.println(value);
}

/*
This section would output:
    The first value is: foo
*/
System.out.println("The first value is: " + FirstString);
```

Things I've considered:

- A class full of static finals. This satisfies #1 and #2, but I can't iterate over them -- at least not without resorting to dark-mojo reflection.
- A dictionary. This satisfies #1 and #3, but the keys wouldn't be auto-completable, and there's additional syntax involved in accessing the values.
- An enum. This also solves #1 and #3, but accessing the string value takes a little bit of extra code.

Is there a data structure, library, etc that will do what I want?

Comment: You can may be override `toString()` in the enum -- but that would be ugly IMO.

Comment: Enum seems the best fit. And why wouldn't you be able to iterate over the static finals? What's stopping you from declaring an array that also contains these values?

Comment: hmm what do the strings represent ? are they inputs from the user ?

Comment: and for the unique name, how would the unique name be calculated ? notice that there are more than hundred unique name for a string unless the name has to have a maximum length, then a truly unique name would be impossible

Comment: The strings are constants, defined before compile-time. In this particular case, they're xpath strings for Selenium WebElements. I want to be able to use them individually (to interact with WebElements) and as a group (to validate that all elements are present).

Comment: @niceman: I'm choosing the unique names myself, choosing names like "pathSubmitButton" and "pathCancelButton". The names only have to be unique within the collection, not within the project (or worldwide).

Comment: do you have a fixed collection of xpath strings or are they going to have arbitrary values and their number is arbitrary ?

Comment: @JornVernee: I could declare an array with those values, but one day when someone edits the code to add/remove some strings, they may forget to update the array. Ideally, I'd like it to be fully self-contained to prevent that.

Comment: @niceman: It's a fixed collection of strings, but it will occasionally change as the system it's testing changes. When that happens, I expect to go back into the code and add/remove/modify strings manually and rebuild.

Comment: Why can't you just use `enum.values()` to get an array of enum values and iterate on it?

Comment: @SurajBajaj: Because if I use an enum, then each time I want to access an individual element's string value, I have to call a method on it. e.g. "foo.name()" versus simply "foo"

Comment: @sprad Then just write a custom method to return string values. Let me put some code in an answer and see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely favor a Map for this:

```
public enum PagePath {
    PATH1,
    PATH2,
    // etc.
}

public static final Map<PagePath, String> ALL_PATHS;
static {
    Map<PagePath, String> paths = new EnumMap<>(PagePath.class);

    paths.put(PagePath.PATH1, "/html/div[0]/h1");
    paths.put(PagePath.PATH2, "/html//form/input[id='firstname']");
    // etc.

    // Make sure no one breaks things by removing entries
    // or by adding enum constants while forgetting to account
    // for them in the above Map.
    if (!paths.keySet().equals(EnumSet.allOf(PagePath.class))) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Map does not have entries for all PagePath constants!");
    }

    ALL_PATHS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(paths);
}
```

Another possibility, as you’ve mentioned, is using String constants.  You can place the initialization of those constants inside the initialization of the “all values” list, to make sure none of them are forgotten:

```
public static final String PATH1;
public static final String PATH2;
// etc.

public static final Collection<String> ALL_PATHS;

static {
    ALL_PATHS = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(
        PATH1 = "/html/div[0]/h1",
        PATH2 = "/html//form/input[id='firstname']",
        // etc.
    ));
}
```

If someone removes a constant, they’ll be forced to remove its initialization from the Arrays.asList call.  If someone adds a constant, and keeps it consistent with the other constants’ declarations, they will be forced to add it to the ALL_PATHS List, since failing to do so would mean it never gets initialized, which compiler will catch.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are properties your may want to use [RessourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) or [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). This can be use to solve problem 1/3.
To solve problem 2, you may create Enum that are Keys to your HashMap so that you need to write hashMap.get(enum) that will auto-complete everything. This solution add words but benefit from auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just write a custom method to return the string values using enum?

```
public enum MagicalDataStructure {
    FirstString("foo"),
    SecondString("bar");

    String value;

    MagicalDataStructure(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static List<String> getMagicalStrings() {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (MagicalDataStructure item : MagicalDataStructure.values()) {
            strings.add(item.value);
        }
        return strings;
    }
}
```

And call the function wherever you need to iterate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String magicalString: MagicalDataStructure.getMagicalStrings()) {
        System.out.println(magicalString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :)  The main idea here is the following we use the EnumMap as a base for our CustomEnumMap. My understanding is that you don't need put methods so our first task is to actually throw Unsupported Operation for them. The second step is to define the different enums with the values they are actually representing. The third step is achieved through a static method that converts any Enumeration into our CustomEnumMap. How the map is later used you can see for yourself.

There is one place for improvement though and it is the implementation of the static method. Unfortunately I am just learning java 8 lambdas so I was not able to implement it fast in a good way. But I will work on that and will give you the final implementation of this method later. Or is someone wants to help me out with it is welcome.

```
 public static class CustomEnumMap<K extends Enum<K>,V> extends EnumMap<K, V> {
            public CustomEnumMap(EnumMap<K, ? extends V> m) {
                super(m);
            }

            @Override
            public V put(K key, V value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }       

        }


        public static enum EnumA {
            FIRST("value1"),SECOND("value2"),THREE("value3");

            private String value;

            private EnumA(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            public String toString() {
                return value;
            }
        }

        public static enum EnumB {
            FIRST("value1"),SECOND("value2");

            private String value;

            private EnumB(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            public String toString() {
                return value;
            }
        }

            public static <T extends Enum<T>> CustomEnumMap<T, String> toMap(T[] myenum) {
                    return new CustomEnumMap<T,String>(new EnumMap<T,String>( Arrays.stream(myenum).collect(Collectors.toMap(t->(T)t, t->t.toString()))));
            }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            CustomEnumMap<EnumA, String> enumA = toMap(EnumA.values());
            CustomEnumMap<EnumA, String> enumB = toMap(EnumA.values());

            for (String stringA : enumA.values()) {
                System.out.print(stringA);

            }
            System.out.println("");
            for (String stringB : enumB.values()) {
                System.out.print(stringB);

            }   
        }
```